# What response time to expect for a cached file to be served from the service worker?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, cacheapi

I noticed that cached files served from a service worker take way to much time according to the Chrome devTools Network tab which shows `Size=(from ServiceWorker)` and `Time=139ms` for a small image file (60x60).

The fetch handler within my service worker has logged a cache hit for this image file so I am sure that the file was served from the cache and not from the network.

Is the `Time` value displayed in the chrome devTools wrong or are 139ms within the range of expected values?